TypeScript can't infer props type inside computed inside setup
I have a component which receives 3 arrays as props, and I want to concatenate them all together before rendering. But I keep getting these TypeScript errors:
<script lang="ts">
import {RisikoentitetRevision, IdentitetsmarkoerRevision, RisikomarkeringRevision} from '@/model/Risikoentitet'
import {defineComponent, computed, PropType} from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HistorikLogTabel',
  props: {
    risikoentitetRevisioner: {
      type: Array as PropType<RisikoentitetRevision[]>,
      required: true,
    },
    identitetsmarkoerRevisioner: {
      type: Array as PropType<IdentitetsmarkoerRevision[][]>,
      required: true,
    },
    risikomarkeringRevisioner: {
      type: Array as PropType<RisikomarkeringRevision[][]>,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    console.log({props})
    const allRevisions = computed(() => {
      console.log("2nd", {props})
      return [
        ...props.risikoentitetRevisioner, // TODO: TS2488: Type 'unknown' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
        ...props.identitetsmarkoerRevisioner.flat(), // TODO: TS2339: Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
        ...props.risikomarkeringRevisioner.flat(), // TODO: TS2339: Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
      ]
    })
    return {
      allRevisions,
    }
  }
})
</script>

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I have tried passing props into the argument in computed but it made no difference.
EDIT:
There is a workaround to ignore the TS errors, and the logic still works as expected. But it is not optimal and I would really like to find out what the TS problem is.
    const allRevisions = computed(() => {
      console.log("2nd", {props})
      return [
        // @ts-ignore
        ...props.risikoentitetRevisioner, // TODO: TS2488: Type 'unknown' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
        // @ts-ignore
        ...props.identitetsmarkoerRevisioner.flat(), // TODO: TS2339: Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
        // @ts-ignore
        ...props.risikomarkeringRevisioner.flat(), // TODO: TS2339: Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
      ]
    })
    console.log({allRevisions})


Composition API has limitations on inferring props from types, not sure if those affect options API and PropType<>. What type do you get for props inside setup()? Are those errors shown in your IDE or during build?

It's unknown where the problem occurs. Does it happen on build? Because if you see it in IDE, it could be specific to it

After doing some more research I realized that I was complicating matters more than necessary. First of all I realized that I was mixing Options API and Composition API. And since my project mostly uses Options API I will stick to that.
I had no need to use setup() when I could just use a simple computed:. Here's the final result that TS was happy with and that worked as expected:
<script lang="ts">
import {RisikoentitetRevision, IdentitetsmarkoerRevision, RisikomarkeringRevision} from '@/model/Risikoentitet'
import {defineComponent, PropType} from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HistorikLogTabel',
  props: {
    risikoentitetRevisioner: {
      type: Array as PropType<RisikoentitetRevision[]>,
      required: true,
    },
    identitetsmarkoerRevisioner: {
      type: Array as PropType<IdentitetsmarkoerRevision[][]>,
      required: true,
    },
    risikomarkeringRevisioner: {
      type: Array as PropType<RisikomarkeringRevision[][]>,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    allRevisions() {
      const revisions = [
        ...this.risikoentitetRevisioner,
        ...this.identitetsmarkoerRevisioner.flat(),
        ...this.risikomarkeringRevisioner.flat(),
      ]
      console.log({revisions}) // Success! ✅
      return revisions
    }
  }
})
</script>

